# How to avoid ambiguity when using strtotime

Tags: php, datetime

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed.

I need to get unixtimestamp from date which is in format `MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS`
According to php.net doc if date separator is dash (-) then `DD-MM-YYYY` format is assumed this returns invalid timestamps.

Is there an alternate to `strtotime()` in PHP 5.2x or any other workaround ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the dashes with slashes:

```
strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', "08-10-2012 09:54:00"));
```